# Optimalizing Django's QuerySetSequences

Tags: python, django, django-views

In one of my views I have problem, that going into this url makes CPU usage 100% for like 5-10 mins. It means that for the next 5-10 mins my webpage is useless.

My bet is that's because of how many database queries I am trying to send.
Views.py that gives me trouble:

```
def guild_details(request, guild_name):
    fixed_guild_name = urllib.parse.unquote(guild_name)
    players = Player.objects.filter(guild=fixed_guild_name)

    last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
    deaths = reduce(QuerySetSequence, [Deaths.objects.filter(killed=player, date__gte=last_month) for player in players])
    kills = reduce(QuerySetSequence, [Deaths.objects.filter(killer=player, date__gte=last_month) for player in players])

    return render(request, 'guild.html', {'players': players,
                                          'deaths': deaths.order_by('-date'),
                                          'kills': kills.order_by('-date'),
                                          'guild_name': guild_name})
```

It seems *not that bad*, but consider that:

- Database includes over 6000+ "Players". (and rising)
- Database includes over 26000+ "Deaths". (and rising)

At first, I was thinking about doing cache for this webpage, but it's deaths / kills might change every 30 mins or so, so I don't think that will help much - considering that I have trouble accessing this page for the **first** time if players count is high (10+). If player count is small, I have no trouble accessing this page.
Also, I'm running redis / celery with scrapping on same server.

Is there something I could optimalize to make it work? Or should I just simply put more CPU into this?

My "top" command:

```
    last pid: 69974;  load averages:  4.28,  4.78,  5.49                                                                                                    up 2+11:16:22  12:40:46
14 processes:  5 running, 9 sleeping
CPU: 33.1% user,  1.4% nice,  6.0% system,  0.0% interrupt, 59.4% idle
Mem: 8965M Active, 30G Inact, 112K Laundry, 82G Wired, 3594M Free
ARC: 64G Total, 41G MFU, 19G MRU, 17M Anon, 857M Header, 2934M Other
     55G Compressed, 97G Uncompressed, 1.76:1 Ratio
Swap:

  PID USERNAME       THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE   C   TIME    WCPU COMMAND
41281 xxxx             1 103    0 65500K 61516K CPU0    0  15:27 100.34% python3.6
42147 xxxx             1 103    0 52956K 48584K CPU1    1   6:33  99.98% python3.6
41637 xxxx             1 103    0 56284K 52352K CPU9    9  14:44  96.18% python3.6
44812 xxxx             1  35   15 65132K 57864K CPU3    3   0:05   0.05% python3.6
51296 xxxx             4  35   15 12444K  7880K kqread  3   0:03   0.03% redis-server
69122 xxxx             1  35   15  7920K  3236K CPU5    5   0:00   0.02% top
40866 xxxx             1  35   15 13192K  8336K select  5   0:00   0.00% sshd
44823 xxxx             1  35   15 73836K 66868K select  2   1:03   0.00% python3.6
93909 xxxx             1  35   15 62060K 55860K select  5   0:04   0.00% python3.6
44811 xxxx             1  35   15  7668K  3688K select  4   0:01   0.00% screen
66149 xxxx             1  21    0  4691M    98M accept  3   0:00   0.00% php-fpm
93908 xxxx             1  35   15  7668K  3708K select  3   0:00   0.00% screen
40867 xxxx             1  35   15  8056K  4336K wait    3   0:00   0.00% bash
51295 xxxx             1  35   15  7668K  3656K select  1   0:00   0.00% screen
```

The first 3 are passenger_wsgi which turns manage.py ON.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here? QuerySetSequence appears to be from a third-party library, but why are you using it? If you want the number of deaths from a set of players in the last month, why not do it in a single query with `__in`, or even a simple join: `Deaths.objects.filter(killed__guild=fixed_guild_name, date__gte=last_month)`?

Comment: Why exactly do you use `QuerySetSequence` here, you can use `__in` to reduce this to a *single* query.

Comment: The for loop is slow. Try to filter the guild in the same statement (line deaths = ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`__in`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup and pass a list of `Player`s here:

```
def guild_details(request, guild_name):
    fixed_guild_name = urllib.parse.unquote(guild_name)
    players = Player.objects.filter(guild=fixed_guild_name)

    last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
    deaths = Deaths.objects.filter(killed__in=players, date__gte=last_month)
    kills = Deaths.objects.filter(killer__in=players, date__gte=last_month)

    return render(request, 'guild.html', {'players': players,
                                          'deaths': deaths.order_by('-date'),
                                          'kills': kills.order_by('-date'),
                                          'guild_name': guild_name})
```

We thus make a query that also performs the `ORDER BY` in the *same* query.